# Multiple Indexes for a Map VS Complex Key

Tags: java, hashmap

I want an indexed collection in Java, but my final Object needs to be indexed by many keys.

I have now a collection of this kind:

```
   Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>>> objects
```

I am asking if this is efficent or it is better to build a more complex key Type to include all of the 5 string keys.

PS:
Sorry i didn't explain the whole thing.
When i try to get an object with this collection the path to this object might be: (call AX the generic key in 1-st position, BX the generic key in 2-th position, etc...) 
 A1 -> B1 -> C1 -> D1 -> E1. But it can be also A1 -> B2 -> C1 -> D1 -> E1.

So i am asking if a complex key that overrides equals to match B2 and B1 as one and match the two described paths it's more efficent than have a nested Map.

Comment: Do you also need to get the intermediate submaps? If not, why not combine all keys into one?

Comment: Will lookups always happen via some combination of all 5 keys?

Comment: "I have now a collection of this kind:" Wow. You should revisit the design choice that led to this.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes i need to, this is what i am doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you need it for. Will you only access the most nested objects, one at the time, or some of the outer maps as well. As an example: Lets assume that `objects` are houses and the map keys are different parts of the address. First one is country, then city, then street, then house number.

If you want to be able to get all houses in city X you problably want to use nested maps like in your example. With complex `Address` class as a key it won't be really possible.

If you don't need that functionality and you will always use all parts then a composite class will be more convenient

**Edit:**

After your edit it seems that a composite class will be a better option. Calling a constructor with meaningful parameter names (as some IDEs show those) will be much nicer than chaining 5 times `.get(String)`.

Comment: No i don't need to get subpaths of this map

Comment: @A.Coluzzi then a composite class should be your choice, see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, i am going to this option too, I am wondering about the memory usages of the two

Comment: As a note, ergeben if you need the sub paths, you can easily create them from the composite using streams and `groupingBy`.

Comment: @A.Coluzzi Honestly, I'm not sure about memory usage. What I'm sure about: don't optimize things prematurely, especially at the cost of readability. It probably won't make any difference unless you're storing millions of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t need a tree structure and you always want to find one stored object. I would suggest to have a compound key. You can concatenate Strings with delimiter as a key.

For two dimensions Table from Guava can be used: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table